# Store Large Amount of Static Data in Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am using Microsoft Azure App Services for host my web site and Azure SQL server for keep my data.for my project SQL Server Database Project to keep all our table, stored procedure, views etc scripts.now I want a way to keep all our static data as well.
Actually my project is hotel related one so i have to keep multiple hotel static data API wise.so currently i'm having more than 3 API.
in future it can be more.but i need to find a way to store those static data.
it should be efficient way because when user request hotel details,i need to get those static data.
(their can be jason files,xml files like wise.)
so what should i do to achive this step?

Project Technical Details
Visual studio 2013
EF
Azure App services & Sql server

Comment: Are these static data uploaded by the developer and used in code or is it something dynamic that users upload during runtime? and what about the file sizes? are there any images or videos?

Comment: There are some jason file 1mb 2mb.no videos and there are only image urls.
yes actually developers update these data and time to time update it.
i ll give example. 
there are more than 2000 hotels in paris.so we store all hotel details room details meal details facilities like wise.so if it is paris yes we have IATA reference code PAR.so we save those static data under PAR.

Comment: Are you going to change these files frequently? if yes, put it on a storage account as blobs and access it from your application using the storage key or you can create a shared access signature and access it directly by the URL

Comment: Perhaps you can store the files in a Redis cache

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions and based on your situation, you are best qualified to pick one.

It sounds like that in this case a thing like Azure Blob Storage or Azure Table Storage is an appropiate solution.

If it is just JSON you need to store, you can also consider an JSON database, like DocumentDB. Maybe you can even put it into Azure SQL DB, which now supports JSON querying.

Finally, if it is read-only and changes only when deploying a new version, I would concider plain old resource dll's